# Arribute to signal what programming language is inside <code> block

Tags: html

### Problem

Is there an attribute which could be used to signal what programming language is used inside `<code>` block?

Something along the lines of `<date>` tag and his `datetime` attribute.

If not, could perhaps some aria attribute be used?

### Context

I have `<code>` blocks with programming language snippets stored inside them, and I need to tell syntax highlight library what language is in these code blocks. Storing that as class feels wrong since that class is not really used for any styling, data-* attribute is what I am currently using, but I wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an attribute which could be used to signal what programming language is used inside `<code>` block?

Nothing specific, but you can use `class`.

> Storing that as class feels wrong since that class is not really used for any styling

`class` is not a "styling" attribute, it is a generic attribute for marking an element as a member of one or more sets of related elements.

Answer (score 0):

[`code` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-code-element) can only have the [global attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-code-element) (apart from `data-*` ones).

It seems there is a perfect global attribute for this: [`lang`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#attr-lang)

> The lang attribute (in no namespace) specifies the primary language
>   for the element's contents and for any of the element's attributes
>   that contain text.

But sadly programming languages are not considered languages:

> Its value must be a valid BCP 47 language tag, or the empty string.

So either use an invalid `lang` attribute, or use a [`data-*` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes):

> [Custom data attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#custom-data-attribute) are intended to store custom data private
>   to the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate
>   attributes or elements.

```
<code data-lang="css">
body { margin: 0; }
</code>
```

Comment: `lang` is definitely wrong. It is for human languages and will be used by, for example, screen readers to select the correct pronunciation dictionary.